# Inserting a Double Customer ID with session

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

i'm new in PHP and i've got a problem in inserting a cus_id = customer ID, and i want to save the customer id in both table in notification and reservation table. here is my code. please comment and suggest. because im new in PHP. please don't down grade me if im wrong thank you. by the way the " function addsched " it can already save the cus_id in databse the only problem is the "function notification " the cus_id is not inserting.

```
function addsched($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,$g,$h,$i,$j,$k)
{
mysql_query("INSERT reservation(type,fname,mname,lname,wfname,wmname,wlname,cfname,res_type,status,cus_id)
values 
('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$h','$i','$j','$k')");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO notification (cus_id,notification)
VALUES('$k','Thank you for reserving in Saint Michael Parish. Your
Current Reservation is still ( PENDING ) ...')");           
}
```

Comment: where is your code? did u forget to post?

Comment: i got a problem in edit my code is not posting. but i post it already.

Comment: Add error handling `if(!mysqli_query(...)) { echo mysqli_error(); }` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO notification (cus_id,notification)
VALUES('$k','Thank you for reserving in Saint Michael Parish. Your
Current Reservation is still ( PENDING ) ...'");
```

Comment: @user3265633 How removal of valid ending parentheses could fix your problem? :)